# Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=; DataItem=null;

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am not sure how to bind this text block in this interaction behavior of the

> Controls:RoundedRectButton

```
    <TextBlock x:Name="Comments"
               Grid.Row="3"
               Grid.Column="3"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Text="{Binding Path=Notiz,
                              Mode=TwoWay}" />

    <Controls:RoundedRectButton x:Name="Bearbeiten"
                                Margin="20,0,0,0"
                                Width="Auto"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Grid.Row="3"
                                Grid.Column="6"
                                Content="Bearbeiten" >
      <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Behaviors:ShowDialogBehavior DialogType="{x:Type Controls:AlphanumericKeyboard}"
                                      EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"
**--->ERROR**                         InputElement="{Binding ElementName=Comments}"
                                      InputProperty="TextBlock.Text"
                                      PrepareCommand="{Binding OpenKeyBoardCommand}"/>
      </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </Controls:RoundedRectButton>
```

I am not sure

1. Relative source
2. Controls:RoundedRectButton.Resources

if these two ways might help, but I am not sure if this make any sense.

Comment: Which one does not bind correctly, `InputElement` or `PrepareCommand`? What is `ShowDialogBehavior`, where did you get it?

Comment: InputElement and PrepareCommand both but as per my understanding PrepareCommand will work fin as soon as the InputElement  get fixed. 

And ShowDialogBehavior is the custom behavior

Comment: Have you confirmed that both bindings fail by debugging? If it is your custom behavior, set a breakpoint and check which one does not get the right value.

Comment: Hey, I tried that but it is not hitting the ShowBehavior on pressing the button